# How to solve "Absolute values cannot be inverted in the complex domain" error in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following equation:

```
Eq(5*Abs(4*x+2)+6,56).
```

What I am trying to do is solve for `x = -3` for the math question `5 |4x+2|+6=56`, but I keep getting the

> "Absolute values cannot be inverted in the complex domain"

error in sympy.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Could you show how you created the variable `x`?

Comment: is `x` a real number ? Sounds like it may be a complex number, which means it cannot be acted upon with `Abs()`

Comment: My code is: x,y = symbols('x y')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify that `x` is a real-valued variable. You can do that when you define the variable as follows.

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x', real = True)
eq = sp.Eq(5*sp.Abs(4*x+2)+6,56)
sol = sp.solve(eq, x)
print(sol)
```

> `[-3, 2]`

EDIT: The `sympy.solveset` function can be used instead of `sympy.solve`. In that case, you need to explicitly state that you are solving over the domain of reals. By doing so, you do not have to define your variable as real.

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x') # implies that x is complex
eq = sp.Eq(5*sp.Abs(4*x+2)+6,56)
sol = sp.solveset(eq, x, domain=sp.S.Reals)
print(sol)
```

> `{-3, 2}`

Comment: It works with solve( ) but not solveset( ). Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @SteveT I have edited the answer to show how it works with `solveset`.